# How to add a row to array with PDO

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

How can I add a row to array using PDO. Previously i did it like this `$message = array('status' => 'ok';` But when I try to use this in PDO like this it does't work

```
 try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$employees['status'] = 'ok';
$employees = array($employees);
    $dbh = null;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo '{"key":'. json_encode($employees) .'}'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$employees = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If you want to typecast `$employees` into an array, you should be using

```
$employees = (array)$employees;
```